# how to say : US dollars 409383

Tags: word-usage

how to spell in English the amount ? 409383 us dollars 
i like to know if it is right: four hundred nine thousand, and three eighty three hundred US Dollars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four hundred and nine thousand, three hundred and eighty three US dollars - in UK English. The two 'and's would generally be omitted in US English. 
BBC English teaching website confirms the former: http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/telugu/course/intermediate/unit-25/session-1

Comment: Hello, Mike. Have you confirmation of the latter also? This answer would then be a lot better than the responses at the 'duplicate'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Only from the fact that every source I find says the same, including dozens of unchallenged comments and answers within this EL&U stack, though I have to admit that I can't easily identify a particularly definitive source.

Comment: I was taught (in American primary school) that we leave the "and"s out of such monetary numbers because of how we're supposed to write them out on a check. In these situations, the "and" is reserved for the decimal point, such as "One hundred forty-two dollars and 99/100" (Just a hopefully-interesting anecdote.)